# Gitlab behind ECS with ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-ecs

Self-hosted GitLab in amazon, everything works as expected besides git clone.
As far as I know, ALB is the 7th layer so it can't send SSH traffic needed for ssh. I would just change the load balancer to classic but in my case, ECS is a must-have. Is there any way to redirect it or anything?
Logs:

```
git clone git@mygit.com:something/nothing.git
Cloning into '...'...
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 123.123.123.123 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

When I try to connect via SSH i get HTTP bad request headers:

```
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.5
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 0: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 1: Server: awselb/2.0
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 2: Date: Thu, 08 Jul 2021 12:05:53 GMT
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 3: Content-Type: text/html
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 4: Content-Length: 122
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 5: Connection: close
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 6: 
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 7: <html>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 8: <head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 9: <body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 10: <center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 11: </body>
debug1: kex_exchange_identification: banner line 12: </html>
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to use an NLB, not ALB.

Comment: Not a suitable idea too, it doesn't have SG and i cant attach certificate...

Comment: You can attach certificates to an NLB. You have to control ingress via the ECS security group instead of the load balancer when you use an NLB. NLB is your only option if you want to pass-through SSH traffic to ECS.